# Stopping custom protocols opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, url

Ive got a url to a custom protocol (i.e. myproto://dosomething) and i can get it to work but when a user clicks on the url it redirects the page before popping up the "do you want to open this url" dialog.

Is there any way to have the custom protocol to work with out the redirect?

For example:

Page:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="myproto://dosomething">My Url</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When user clicks link, browser redirects to blank page with myproto://dosomething as url and shows popup. What im trying to do is have it so that the popup shows but stays on the main page.

Comment: What do you mean by redirect? Show us some code.

Comment: I dont care about the acceptance, just want the page that the link to the custom url is on to not be redirected to blank

Comment: By "I can get it to work" do you mean that you've got an event handler that handles links with a custom protocol? If so, you need to prevent the default behavior of the event by using `e.preventDefault()` where `e` is the event object.

Comment: Does it happen when you click "open in new tab" or when normally clicking it? I'd say blame the browser manufacturer, not your page. Which browser is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i found a solution to this issue: iframes

```
var launchLink = function(href) {
    var url = ProtoRedirectUrl + '?' + $.param({ url: href });
    $('<iframe src="' + url + '" width="1px" height="1px">').appendTo('body');
}
```

This causes the url to be loaded and the browser redirects the iframe window to the blank page instead of the main window.

Comment: Hi, I used this for myself, but it doesn't work if you are in a secure page...  Have you come across this?

Comment: This is the best solution, especially if the URL scheme isn't supported.

Comment: @HannesNZ Content Security Policy issue? Use the [sandbox <iframe> attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp).

Comment: @HannesNZ You may just have to add "myproto:" to CSP's default-src.