# html does it have a try, catch like c#?

Tags: javascript, html, skype

I love to use try catch on a lot of my programs in C#.  I was working on a website and I was using:

```
<a href="skype:freepcadvice?call">Call 555-555-5555</a>
```

But if they don't have skype of course there is an error, which I would like to redirect to say something like "Skype not installed, here is a download link".  I am guessing this would probably have to be handled by Java script, but wasn't sure if HTML had such a feature?

Comment: On Firefox I get a native "The address wasn't understood" error. I find it clear already. I don't think you can't detect it to customize it.

Comment: [Check if Custom URL scheme is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571548/javascript-how-to-detect-if-the-custom-url-scheme-is-available-or-not-availabl)  ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML is a mark up / display language.  It does not have any conditions or methods to handle errors.  You could use JavaScript, or a server side language like c# or php.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little complicated. What you want to do is detect whether or not Skype is installed on an end-users computer, and that isn't trivial.

You can view some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358397/javascript-to-detect-skype), but it requires a bit of sophistication with JavaScript, and uses jQuery to boot. Good luck!